# Slug from database available on all pages through lang CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table on my database from where I get some slug texts:

- art_and_culture
- business_and_financial
- auto_and_moto

and display on my website through

```
<?php echo lang($slug_from_database); ?>
```

I use this method as LanguageSwticher:

[multi-language-support-in-codeigniter](http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-language-support-in-codeigniter/)

So in My_Controller.php I have in construct:

```
    $this->categories_list = $this->categories_model->entries();
    $list_categories['categories'] = $this->categories_list;
    $this->data['sidebar_categories'] = $this->load->view('blocks/sidebar_categories', $list_categories, TRUE);
```

and all the categories are available on all pages from my website. The problem is when I send to the view the categories, the language is not set from the LanguageLoader.php controller witch is initialised in hooks.php (see the link example). If no language no text on echo $slug_from_database. How do you suggest to do?

Comment: you should add some more details..

Comment: The main problem is that the hook LanguageLoader.php fire up after MY_Controller.php construct. So I have no language in the construct when I try to echo lang('something'); .

Comment: I gaved an answer to my question. What can you tell me about it?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution:

Created:

```
    public function LanguageLoader() {

        $site_lang = $this->session->userdata('site_lang');
    if ($site_lang) {
        $this->lang->load('message',$this->session->userdata('site_lang'));
    } else {
        $this->lang->load('message', $this->config->item('language'));

    }
}
```

in MY_Controller.php

and call it in the constructor: $this->LanguageLoader();

and delete

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
'class' => 'LanguageLoader',
'function' => 'initialize',
'filename' => 'LanguageLoader.php',
'filepath' => 'hooks'
```

);

from hooks.php so now I load the language in controller`s construct not with hook.